# Time sleep not working in loop after printing a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".", end=" ")
```

I just want to make kind of loading screen by make dots appear after one second and I was expecting 
this-

`.{wait}.{wait}.{wait}.{wait}`

But I didn't got any output but after closing program by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> I got the output like this-

````
. . . . . . . . . . . . Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Piyush/Desktop/Python/dotdotdotload.py", line 12, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt```
````

Comment: Try using `print(".", end=" ", flush=True)`

Comment: it works, XD thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the output and it will display:

Python-3.x: https://repl.it/repls/DarksalmonFussyBooleanalgebra

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".", end=" ", flush=True)
```

Python-2.7: https://repl.it/repls/CuteTenseRoutes

```
import sys
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print ". ",
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: thanks for the effort you made to make a whole lot of code :)